# Why does the IronKey executable on Ubuntu 11.10 fail when executed?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, usb-storage

When I plug my IronKey into my Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit laptop, the read-only partition mounts as usual at /media/Ironkey. However, when I change into the /media/IronKey/linux/ directory and try to execute the ironkey executable via ./ironkey, it returns the following:

```
bash: ./ironkey: No such file or directory
```

I have lib32gcc1 installed, and this used to work fine but all the sudden does not. Any ideas?

Comment: By chance, did you unplug your IronKey without doing an eject?

Comment: Possibly, but it works just fine on my Mac, and I made sure to lock it before unplugging it from my Mac the last time I used it...

Comment: I'm having same issue - any joy getting it to work?

Comment: Nope... not yet anyway. :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu, try

```
# apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

which worked for me.

Comment: The original poster already said he was on Ubuntu and **had** `lib32gcc1` installed...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be related to the Linux kernel being modified.  You would probably need to contact IK to see if they have a patch available.